# A tree edge $uv$ with $u$ as $v$’s parent is a cut edge if and only if there are no edges in $v$’s subtree that goes to $u$ or higher

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

Referring to these notes regarding DFS - [Click Here](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~rpeng/CS3510_F16/notes/Sep28DFS.pdf)

They refer to the following claim that follows Definition 0.2. as observation:

> A tree edge $uv$ with $u$ as $v$’s parent is a cut edge if and only if there are no edges in $v$’s subtree that goes to $u$ or higher.

However, I don't really understand why is that obvious or how can it be proved.

I'd appreciate a proof of this claim.

Comment: As time goes by, it will become obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

We must prove two directions: (i) if $uv$ is a cut edge, then there is no edge from $v$'s subtree to $u$ or higher and (ii) if there is no edge from $v$'s subtree to $u$ or higher, then $uv$ is a cut edge.

For (i), if there was an edge from $v$'s subtree to $u$ or higher, then the removal of $uv$ would not increase the number of connected components contradicting the fact that $uv$ is a cut edge. To prove (ii), since every path from any vertex in a subtree of $v$ to a vertex that is $u$ (or higher than $u$) must use the edge $uv$, we see that $uv$ is indeed a cut edge.